# Amazon Redshift char to time conversion

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a table in Amazon Redshift where the time column is a string type and stores values as HH:MM form. I need to convert this to time format to do some further processing. I tried ::time which raised "Unknown data type in extract result set" error. To_date(my_field, 'HH:MM') didn't work either.

Char HH:MM to time HH:MM

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Amazon Redshift does not have a `TIME` datatype. What processing do you want to do? It might be possible to convert it to a `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Datetime format strings - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_FORMAT_strings.html):

- To convert a 24-hour 2-digit hour, use `HH24`
- To convert minutes, use `MI`

Therefore, try: `TO_TIMESTAMP(field, 'HH24:MI')`

See also: [TO_TIMESTAMP function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_TIMESTAMP.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot John!
The problem I'm having with TO_TIMESTAMP() is that it adds some date values to the output. For egxample: TO_TIMESTAMP('14:56', 'HH24:MI') returns 0001-01-01 14:56:00+00 BC. I was hoping to get 14:56 so that I can do further processing such as dateadd(minute, minute_int, myFiled). Is there a way around this?

Comment: I wonder whether an `INTERVAL` would suit your purpose? You could convert the `TIMESTAMP` to an `INTERVAL` by using the above code, but then subtracting a timestamp of midnight. Perhaps something like `TO_TIMESTAMP(field, 'HH24:MI') - '0001-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp`. You could then add that `INTERVAL` to another date/timestamp.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it might even work as `field::interval` to convert it to an interval.

Comment: Thank you for your help John! The following worked
TO_CHAR(dateadd(minute, min_field, TO_TIMESTAMP(time_field, 'HH24:MI')::timestamp), 'HH24:MI')